# Calling a method within a method which takes list of classes

Tags: python

I am new to object oriented programming & trying to build a problem. Below are some classes and methods defined:

```py
@dataclass
class ProductionTask:
    id: int
    processingtime: int
    duration: float
    done: bool
    start_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    end_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    production_equipment: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG


@dataclass
class TransferTask:
    id: int
    min_transfer_duration: float
    max_transfer_duration: float
    done: bool
    start_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    end_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    equipment_item: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG



@dataclass
class ProductionEquipment:
    id: int
    production_tasks: List[ProductionTask] | None = None
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG


@dataclass
class TransferEquipment:
    id: int
    transfer_tasks: List[TransferTask] | None = None
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG

@dataclass
class Stage:
    id: int
    production_equipment: List[ProductionEquipment] | None = None
    transfer_equipment: List[TransferEquipment] | None = None
```

This is a method defined for stage class:

```py
  def unassigned_production_tasks(self,task:List[ProductionTask]):
        """This method takes in task class and checks in each stage if any
           of the task has an unassigned flag, if yes, it appends it to
           a list and returns a list of task class named unassigned production task """

        # for id in self.id:
        if self.id <= 1:
            print(f'{self.id is 1}')
            return
        if self.production_equipment is None:
            print('Stage has ProductionEquipment None')
            return
        unassigned_production_task_list = []
        for equipment in self.production_equipment:
            if equipment.production_tasks is None:
                continue
            for task in equipment.production_tasks:
                if task.start_time == UNASSIGNED_FLAG:
                    unassigned_production_task_list.append(task)
        return unassigned_production_task_list
```

When I try to use this method this way , in another method, it raises error, I am unsure, how to resolve it?

```py
   def feasible_production_tasks_in_stage(self):
        production_tasks = self.unassigned_production_tasks(List[ProductionTask])
        transfer_tasks = self.completed_transfer_tasks(List[TransferTask],self._time)
        feasible_production_tasks = []
        for task in production_tasks :
            if task in transfer_tasks and task.stage == self.id -1:
                feasible_production_tasks.append(task)
```

Anyone can please guide me ?

I am unsure about the input arguments of calling method within a method.

Comment: Have you defined any object called `List`? Or you are just using [`List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) from [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module? If `List` is a list, you need an integer to access its elements. If you want to pass the whole list to `unassigned_production_tasks` then just write the name of your list as an argument.

Comment: You are using wrong the argument `task`in your function `unassigned_production_tasks`. You cannot access to the argument because the loop `for task in equipment.production_tasks` shadows the name `task`.